# Enviar formulario perl con Mechanize manteniendo la sesión

Tags: perl, mechanize

Necesito enviar el formulario de login de una URL y cargar la página a la que se accede una vez logueado en el navegador por defecto. He conseguido a través de mechanize obtener la URL, loguearme y obtener la URL siguiente al loguin e incluso abrirla en el navegador. Pero en cuanto navego por la web me vuelve a pedir que inicie sesión.

Entiendo que porque lo único que he hecho ha sido "pintar" lo que me devuelve mechanize sin estar realmente logueado en la sesión que abre el navegador.

Mi idea sería primero abrir la página de login en el navegador y una vez ahí rellenar los campos del formulario y enviarlo con lo cual la sesión ya sí estaría iniciada en el navegador.

¿Es posible hacer esto? No encuentro nada de información sobre ello.

Comment: Me parece que faltan datos para poder responder. ¿En dónde está corriendo tu script? ¿Cuál es el objetivo de todo esto? ¿Qué mecanismo ya la web para gestionar las credenciales del usuario?

Comment: Ahora mismo el script está corriendo en local aunque no descarto que me hagan hacerlo desde servidor (aún no está definido). Quiero hacer una prueba de concepto y ver que se puede realmente. El objetivo es poder logarse en una aplicación y mostrar al usuario la información que le devuelve una vez logado. No dispongo de mucha más información.

Comment: Si la sesión se guarda por medio de _cookies_ desde el lado del cliente, quizás Mechanize no las esté guardando bien.

Comment: @camunha deberías añadir la parte relevante del script en la pregunta